# Django form selected option not recognized, failed if statement

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a select field that should keep it's selected value even after an error (e.g. a required filed is empty), but it cannot match the current value.

```
<label for="{{ form.movie.id_for_label }}" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Movie:</label>
<select id="{{ form.movie.id_for_label }}" name="movie" class="form-control">
{% for x,y in form.fields.movie.choices %}
    <option value="{{ x }}"{% if form.movie.value == x %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ y }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

If I select the value 2, then after an error the form.movie.value has the value 2, but in the code in thy loop when x = 2, the equation won't give back true, so no selected value will be kept.

Why is it, where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that ***form.fields.movie.choices*** returns the id as a number (int I guess), and the data in ***form.movie.value*** is a string, so to compare the two the ***x*** needs to be casted to string like so: ***x|stringformat:"s"***, and then the two can be compared without any problem.